# Google map import geojson

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am trying to make a google map with markers on it. Should be a really easy task. However, it keeps throwing errors to me saying "cannot read property 'addGeoJson' of undefined" or  "cannot read property 'loadGeoJson' of undefined". Anyone could help me figure out why? Thank you so much!

I've tried many different ways to import the data. (The data is a link to a geojson file. The geojson file is validated. Below use map.json as a spaceholder):

```
var add_data = $.getJSON("map.json"); 
  add_data.then(function(data){
    cachedGeoJson = data; 
    console.log(cachedGeoJson);
    map.data.addGeoJson(cachedGeoJson,{idPropertyName:"id"});  
  });

 or: 
 map.data.loadGeoJson('map.json');

 or: 
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = 'map.json';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 function eqfeed_callback(results) {
 map.data.addGeoJson(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson) method is:

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
```

That works for me.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jybkfdwo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    }
  });

  // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```